# Appropriate "tool" to do graphs with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have a network of nodes, I know the location of each node thanks to GPS, and wonna represent the nodes distribution (something like a map) using eclipse... 
I tried with "Zest" but didn't get a the wanted results. 
What is the best way to do that?
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Why is this question tagged eclipse ?
This sort of data should be shown on a map, if you want to do it interactively try using google earth.  if you want to do it programmatically in eclipse, you could go with javascript and the google maps api, or check out Udig (http://udig.refractions.net/) for a full blown GIS based on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

As @Gabe already said the question is not about eclipse. You should look at [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html), I think it's the most popular library for drawing graphs in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes I want to do that programatically using eclipse, that's why I've posted my question here...                        Sorry anyway